# Python Regex : What's wrong with this?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a regex to just get the error code from this XML.

```
>>> re_code = re.compile(r'<errorcode>([0-9]+)</errorcode>', re.MULTILINE)
>>> re_code.match('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
... <methoderesponse>
...     <status>
...         <message/>
...         <errorcode>515</errorcode>
...         <value>ERROR</value>
...     </status>
... </methoderesponse>
... ''')
```

It should be quite easy. But I don't understand why it doesn't match.

Comment: when dealing with regular expressions, you should also include your input AND expected output so we can better help you.

Comment: @InbarRose: input and expected output are in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @[Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) has said, `.match()` only works if the expression is supposed to run from the beginning of the string, `.search()` searches the string for the first occurrence, and `.findall()` searches for all the occurrences.

but regardless of that, you should modify slightly your regular expression to a slightly more readable version:

```
regex = re.compile(r'<errorcode>(\d+)</errorcode>')
```

you don't need the `re.MULTILINE` argument, it does not pertain to this problem.

Answer (score 8):

`.match()` attempts to match at the start. You want `.search()` or more likely `.findall()`

Have a look at an XML parser though - much nicer to use XPath or equivalent to get your data (plus it'll handle nuances that regex's won't)

An example that works with your sample XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(text)

>>> tree.findall('.//errorcode')[0].text
'515'
```

More info about [ElementTree here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and I would personally check out [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Comment: I don't want to use etree for just this.